# FFmpeg how to get an image for a particular 'coded_picture_number' together with motion vectors

Tags: vector, ffmpeg, video-processing

I am looking for ways to get this output from ffmpeg:

[image]

Basically, I would like to pass to the shell, a command that allows me to output a particular frame number, let's say `coded_picture_number=200` with the motion vectors drawn into it.

Any clue? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This

```
ffmpeg -flags2 +export_mvs -i video.avi -vf 'select=gte(n\,200),codecview=mv=pf+bf+bb' -vframes 1 frame.png
```

will open `video.avi`, skip first 200 frames (`n` starts from 0), visualize motion vectors (all types), and writes exactly 1 frame into `frame.png`.

Comment: Thank you so much! Works perfectly well.