# how to get motion vector by HEVC method?

Tags: c++, video-encoding, hevc, libx265

I want to get the motion vector between two frames. I want to use the motion estimation method in x265. But I don't know how to do?

Anyone can help me?

Thank you!!!

I used to download the source code of x265, but it is too difficult to understand and extract related motion estimation code.

Comment: If you only want to visualize them, you can use FFmpeg: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48992849/1729784

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].